# Does restful_authentiation work in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

does restful authentication work in rails 3?

Is devise the new standard?

I would love for an authentition system to support website registration + twitter and openid, does devise do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise seems to be the new standard, I think it's a great auth solution and has support for pluggable auth strategies.

Checkout [Janrain engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage).  They offer a free solution that lets you connect through numerous auth portals.  It also works seamlessly into devise. There's a great [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/233-engage-with-devise) that outlines how to achieve this.

Comment: i'm fairly new, is it complicated to use? (devise)

Comment: nope, super simple,  check out the docs on the repo https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.  They give you a generator so you can simply at it to your Gemfile and run `rails generate devise:install`  The docs are quite good so you can go from there.

Comment: Toronto!!  No, there's a huge Rails community here,  Unspace runs a Rails Pub night every month, there are always tons of recruiters.  It's super easy to get a job here :)

Comment: huge? i heard it was small!  what's the pay range like? thanks!

Comment: well i have nothing to compare it to so I have no idea, but it seems pretty big to me.  Monthly at the RPN nights there are always 30-40 people, and that's just the Rails developers who like to drink :p  I would assume there are many more in the city.  Salary ranges from $50k - $70k ??

Comment: interesting, appreciate the info. btw u need a blog or something! no link in u'r profile.

Comment: ya haven't gotten around blog'ng yet... maybe get my company to start up a dev blog.